Have past US presidential candidates sued to be removed from the ballot?
Robert F. Kennedy Jr. is apparently suing several states that would not remove him from the ballot after he announced he's pulling out of the race. Some states invoked technical or financial reasons, e.g. they already printed millions of ballots with his name on them (costing hundreds of thousand of dollars).
Is this a unique situation? Have some other past presidential candidates sued to be removed from the ballot?

The most similar case I can think of is Ross Perot in 1992, a third-party candidate who withdrew from the race that July.  During his withdrawal, there were attempts to remove him from state ballots, but some states refused due to deadlines having passed.  One disappointed Perot campaign worker from Florida filed a lawsuit to force Perot to remain in the race, but it was dropped.
Then, on October 1, 1992, Perot changed his mind and decided to re-enter the Presidential race after all, making removing his name from ballots a moot issue.
